# Google Sheet Import Ljava.lang.Object error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have pieced together a few different scripts to get this to work but I cant seem to get the code to put the data in correctly.

**Email Input:**

```
*Status:* 
*Date:* 03/31/2020
*WorkOrder:* 123456-1
*DMSShipDate:* 03/31/2020
*PONumber:* 8675309
*Company:* Test
```

**Script**

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
function onOpen(e){

  ui.createMenu("Import Email").addItem("Import Email", "getGmailEmails").addToUi();

}

function getGmailEmails(){  
    if (Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() != "email@gmail.com"){
        Browser.msgBox("Please log in as email@gmail.com");
        return;
    }
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("ImportMe");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for(var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j = 0; j <messages.length; j++){
      var message = messages[j];
      extractDetails(message);
      GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);

  }

}

function extractDetails(message){
    var bodyContents = message.getPlainBody();
    var status = bodyContents.match(/\*Status:\*(.*) /);
    var dateEntered =  bodyContents.match(/\*Date:\*(.*) /);
    var workOrder = bodyContents.match(/\*WorkOrder:\*(.*) /);
    var dmsShipDate =  bodyContents.match(/\*DMSShipDate:\*(.*) /);
    var poNum =  bodyContents.match(/\*PONumber:\*(.*) /);
    var company =  bodyContents.match(/\*Company:\*(.*) /);

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.appendRow([status, dateEntered, workOrder, dmsShipDate, poNum, company]);
}
```

**Result:**

```
I get the following in each column:
[Ljava.lang.Object;@488e1851, [Ljava.lang.Object;@5c588720, etc, etc
```

I have tried JSON.Stringify and toString() but nothing seems to be able to get the data into the column correctly.

Comment: what does `string.match()` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns a `array`. To get the captured group, index into that array:

```
bodyContents.match(/\*Status:\*(.*) /)[1];
```

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null.

Comment: @Jakesch - well, that''s because `match()` returns an `Array` **or** `null` (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) - TheMaster's answer first link, btw) on no match. The rest depends on whether you expect a non-match (something like `(someString.match(SomeExp)||[,""])[1]` should suffice).